# How to call methods overloaded by parameter type in F#?

Tags: c#, generics, f#, overloading

I'm struggling to call a method (from a C# library) that's overloaded by parameter type, according to a generic parameter

In the following example I've used an F# class with overloaded methods instead, to illustrate the point.  It's key that the generic parameter could be either a `struct` or a reference type, and it could be a derived type of one of the relevant parameter types (I've used `StreamWriter` here to illustrate that).

```
open System.IO

type MyClass() =
    member this.Method(n: int) = sprintf "Integer %i" n
    member this.Method(s: string) = sprintf "String %s" s
    member this.Method(w: TextWriter) = sprintf "Some kind of text writer"

let passValueToCorrectMethod (c: MyClass) (value: 'a) : string =
    match value with
    | :? int as n -> c.Method(n) // ERROR: Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types
    | :? string as s -> c.Method(s)
    | :? TextWriter as w -> c.Method(w)

// what I want to be able to do with it
let c = MyClass()
let sw = new StreamWriter("C:\temp\blah")

let result1 = passValueToCorrectMethod c 5
let result2 = passValueToCorrectMethod c "hi"
let result3 = passValueToCorrectMethod c sw
```

Comment: If you change `value: 'a` to `value: obj` then it'll compile (with a warning that you're not handling other types).

Comment: Thanks... thought I had tried that and it failed because of the `int` being a struct, but it does indeed seem to work.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668106/f-pattern-matching-by-type) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026965/runtime-coercion-of-generic-types-in-f) basically cover it. The gist is you can't do runtime type tests for value types, so you need to either box it (`match box value with`) or change the parameter type to `obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `value: 'a` to `value: obj` (as suggested by @Charles Mager) and optionally add a catch all case: `_ -> failwith "No overload"`. Or, if you are willing to use reflection:

```
let passValueToCorrectMethod (c: MyClass) (value: 'a) : string =
    let valueType = typeof<'a>
    let mi = c.GetType().GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public, null, [| valueType |], null)
    if isNull mi then
        failwithf "No overload for %s" valueType.Name
    else    
        mi.Invoke(c, [| value |]) |> string

// what you'll be able to do with it
let c = MyClass()
let sw = new StreamWriter(".\\temp.txt")

passValueToCorrectMethod c sw // Some kind of text writer
passValueToCorrectMethod c () // Runtime Exception: No overload for Unit
```

This way it works when adding / removing `Method`s without a change to `passValueToCorrectMethod`. Anyways you lose compile time safety.